# Display result of an Entity Framework query in a view

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm new to Entity Framework, I want to display the result of a query which was performed in a controller on my view page.

Here is my code in the controller I don't know where to go from here please help I appreciate any help from any one thanks:

```
public ActionResult StartQiz()
{          
    using (var question = new Quizdb()) 
    {    
          var quest = (from q in question.Exams
                       where q.ExamType.StartsWith("C#")
                       select q);

          ViewBag.querry = quest;
    }

    return View();
}
```

Comment: Just check this link: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application It explains all the basics.

Comment: The tutorial on this link is making use of the builtin CRUD operation template, I actually want to make a kind of select  like Question and Answer options as in Quiz exercise.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass the query result to ViewBag.just return the result to the view.(right click on View(quest) then choose add view ;in case that you don't have corresponding ViewModel class)

```
public ActionResult StartQiz()
{         
    using (var question = new Quizdb()) 
    {    
          var quest = (from q in question.Exams
                       where q.ExamType.StartsWith("C#")
                       select q).ToList();
          return View(quest);
    }  
}
```

Comment: He also needs to have the view accepting the corresponding model type.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i got this error message when i run the application with the code above:"The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ExaminationPortal.Models.Exams]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'ExaminationPortal.Models.Exams'."

Comment: Type of model which you have in view is different form the query result.if you can remove the view(if it doesn't have any side effect) or change  type of model that you have in view from ExaminationPortal.Models.Exams to list<ExaminationPortal.Models.Exams> then iterate the list with foreach

Comment: Please can you help me with a solution on how i can use Update panel in mvc?

Comment: honestly I can't because I don't know some much about update panel.ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently using the ViewBag object to pass your data from action method to the view. This can be done, but you might want consider using the model approach.

```
public ActionResult StartQiz()
{          
    using (var question = new Quizdb()) 
    {    
      var quest = (from q in question.Exams
                       where q.ExamType.StartsWith("C#")
                       select q);


      return View(quest);
    }
} `
```

In your view the first line should declare the model:

```
 @model IEnumerable<Type>
```

Then you can access your data like this:

```
@foreach(var exam in Model) 
{
   <p>exam.Title</p>
}
```

Comment: this actually work when i used  @model IEnumerable<Type> but it only work for    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.C) and throw when i use    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.C) to get option, now i can only get the headings but cant get the questions and options